# Hardware audio keyboard keys stopped working

Tags: volume-control, keyboard-accelerators

I have hardware "volume up" and "volume down" on my Lenovo Thinkpad W530. They used to work to increase and decrease volume. A day or two ago, they stopped working. xev sees them, in settings>keyboard>shortcuts, they are correctly assigned, I can assign other key combinations to change volume and that works, I can also assign the hardware keys to different actions and that does not work. It works for a guest account. Reboot does not help. I am at a loss what might be causing it. Any ideas where to look for causes? This is on 14.04.

Comment: Oddly enough, they work in mpv (but only change the internal mpv volume setting). And they also work in vlc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1302885).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptoms with 14.04.

I imagined that VLC had 'grabbed' the media keys so I removed VLC. The problem persisted ...

I followed a reset suggestion that I found on the web:

Open a terminal and enter,

```
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
 gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
```

This didn't seem to have any effect (which is why I closed the page and lost the link!). So I reinstalled VLC. But the next time I used an audio application I discovered that the media keys were working.

Maybe it was just luck and the keys will stop working again, but for now I'm a happy bunny :-)

Comment: Can you add the source to those commands please?

Comment: 'Fraid that I lost the link when it didn't seem to fix the problem straight away.

Comment: Well, the commands can be found in the bug I linked in my answer. It indeed fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is what happens. Expect it to randomly not work after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
keyboard>shortcuts>sound and media>
```

Then, redefine volume shortcuts (using those volume keys of your keyboard)